# Glue cx_oracle error : "Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so"

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, cx-oracle

I am trying to establish a connection from AWS glue to oracle using cx_oracle, so for that, I added --additional-python-modules as cx_Oracle==8.3 in job parameters. When I try to execute "conn=cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@host/service name")", I am getting the below error:

DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

Can someone please help with the issue?

Edit: was able to resolve the above error but for some reason the following error is not getting resolved**DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804**

Comment: One suggestion: try using python-oracledb (the new module intended to replace cx_Oracle) in thin mode -- which doesn't need any Oracle Client library.

Comment: The release announcement for python-oracledb has the details about it superseding cx_Oracle, and has links, see [here](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: I tried adding python-oracledb==1.1 in job parameter but.......the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oracledb' " is popping up wile running

Comment: Try adding `oracledb==1.1`

Comment: Yes I did that but then again "NotSupportedError: DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode" this error is popping up